# Rails number_to_currency bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error in view, when I have set the default locale to danish.

I have change the locale to default english. I still get the error.

**Development log:**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-08 22:53:48 +0100
  Processing by PublicController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mKonkurrancer Load (5.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`[0m
Rendered public/index.erb within layouts/application (107.0ms)
Completed   in 306ms

ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't parse YAML at line 0 column 0):
    13:    <tr onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#99ff33';this.style.cursor='pointer'">
    14:       <td width="320px" style="padding-left: 5px;"><%= truncate(vind.name.force_encoding("UTF-8"), :length => 55) %></td>
    15:       <td>4 ud af 5</td>
    16:       <td><%= number_to_currency(vind.vaerdi, :locale => :da) %></td>
    17:       <td>2 min</td>
    18:       <td>Nyhedsbrev</td>
    19:       <td><%= vind.udtraekkes.strftime("%d %B") %></td>
  app/views/public/index.erb:16:in `block in _app_views_public_index_erb___358071530_34835700_285053873'
  app/views/public/index.erb:12:in `each'
  app/views/public/index.erb:12:in `_app_views_public_index_erb___358071530_34835700_285053873'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (59.0ms)
```

Da locale:

```
da:
  # active_support
  date:
    # See http://sproget.dk/svarbase/SV00000046/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_formats
    # either use traditional (2.10.03, 2. oktober 2003): "%e.%m.%y", "%e. %B %Y"
    # or international ISO 8601 format (2003-10-20): "%Y-%m-%d"
    # Note: some Windows distributions do not support %e - you may have to use %d instead
    formats:
      default: "%d.%m.%Y"
      short: "%e. %b %Y"
      long: "%e. %B %Y"

    day_names: [søndag, mandag, tirsdag, onsdag, torsdag, fredag, lørdag]
    abbr_day_names: [sø, ma, ti, 'on', to, fr, lø] # Note: unescaped 'on' is parsed as true
    month_names: [~, januar, februar, marts, april, maj, juni, juli, august, september, oktober, november, december]
    abbr_month_names: [~, jan, feb, mar, apr, maj, jun, jul, aug, sep, okt, nov, dec]
    order: [ :day, :month, :year ]

  time:
    formats:
      default: "%e. %B %Y, %H:%M"
      short: "%e. %b %Y, %H:%M"
      long: "%A, %e. %B %Y, %H:%M"
    am: ""
    pm: ""

  support:
    array:
      # Rails 2.2
      #sentence_connector: "og"
      #skip_last_comma: true
      # Rails 2.3
      words_connector: ", "
      two_words_connector: " og "
      last_word_connector: " og "
    select:
      # default value for :prompt => true in FormOptionsHelper
      prompt: "Vælg..."

  # action_view
  number:
    format:
      separator: ","
      delimiter: "."
      precision: 3
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false

    currency:
      format:
        format: "%u %n"
        unit: "DKK"
        separator: ","
        delimiter: "."
        precision: 2
        significant: false
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false

    percentage:
      format:
        delimiter: ""

    precision:
      format:
        delimiter: ""

    human:
      format:
        delimiter: ""
        precision: 3
        significant: true
        strip_insignificant_zeros: true
      # Rails 2.2
      #storage_units: [Bytes, KB, MB, GB, TB]
      # Rails 2.3
      storage_units:
        # Storage units output formatting.
        # %u is the storage unit, %n is the number (default: 2 MB)
        format: "%n %u"
        units:
          byte:
            one: "Byte"
            other: "Bytes"
          kb: "KB"
          mb: "MB"
          gb: "GB"
          tb: "TB"
      decimal_units:
        format: "%n %u"
        units:
          unit: ""
          thousand: Tusind
          million: Million
          billion: Milliard
          trillion: Billion
          quadrillion: Billiard

  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      half_a_minute: "et halvt minut"
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one: "mindre end et sekund"
        other: "mindre end %{count} sekunder"
      x_seconds:
        one: "et sekund"
        other: "%{count} sekunder"
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one: "mindre end et minut"
        other: "mindre end %{count} minutter"
      x_minutes:
        one: "et minut"
        other: "%{count} minutter"
      about_x_hours:
        one: "cirka en time"
        other: "cirka %{count} timer"
      x_days:
        one: "en dag"
        other: "%{count} dage"
      about_x_months:
        one: "cirka en måned"
        other: "cirka %{count} måneder"
      x_months:
        one: "en måned"
        other: "%{count} måneder"
      about_x_years:
        one: "cirka et år"
        other: "cirka %{count} år"
      over_x_years:
        one: "mere end et år"
        other: "mere end %{count} år"
      almost_x_years:
        one: "næsten et år"
        other: "næsten %{count} år"
    prompts:
      year: "År"
      month: "Måned"
      day: "Dag"
      hour: "Time"
      minute: "Minut"
      second: "Sekund"

  helpers:
    select:
      prompt: "Vælg..."

    submit:
      create: "Opret %{model}"
      update: "Opdater %{model}"
      submit: "Gem %{model}"

  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

    messages: &errors_messages
      inclusion: "er ikke i listen"
      exclusion: "er reserveret"
      invalid: "er ikke gyldig"
      confirmation: "stemmer ikke overens med bekræftelse"
      accepted: "skal accepteres"
      empty: "må ikke udelades"
      blank: "skal udfyldes"
      too_long: "er for lang (maksimum %{count} tegn)"
      too_short: "er for kort (minimum %{count} tegn)"
      wrong_length: "har forkert længde (skulle være %{count} tegn)"
      not_a_number: "er ikke et tal"
      not_an_integer: "er ikke et heltal"
      greater_than: "skal være større end %{count}"
      greater_than_or_equal_to: "skal være større end eller lig med %{count}"
      equal_to: "skal være lig med %{count}"
      less_than: "skal være mindre end %{count}"
      less_than_or_equal_to: "skal være mindre end eller lig med %{count}"
      odd: "skal være ulige"
      even: "skal være lige"

  activerecord:
    errors:s
      template:
        header:
          one: "En fejl forhindrede %{model} i at blive gemt"
          other: "%{count} fejl forhindrede %{model} i at blive gemt"
        body: "Der var problemer med følgende felter:"

      messages:
        taken: "er allerede brugt"
        record_invalid: "Validering fejlede: %{errors}"
        <<: *errors_messages

      full_messages:
        format: "%{att
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the relevant locale file? (`config/locales/da.yml` if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I have now posted the da.yml locale file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted my danish locale and did add some space at the end of my yaml files.